# Does this implementation work?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Deall all,

I'm designing a vehicle registration system using DDD. It is required to archive the registrations of all vehicles so that the registrations of a vehicle over its lifetime can be easily read.

To implement this requirement, I am going to simply treat "REGISTRATION"s as a collection in a VEHICLE, as shown below:

```cs
//The Aggregation Root
public class Vehicle
{        
    GUID id;

    List<Registration> registrations_;
    ......
    public Vehicle() { ..... }
    ...
}

//The Value Object
public class Registration
{

  Vehicle vehicle_;
  decimal amount_;
  ......

  //The calendar interval for a single registration.
  Period period_;

  public Registration() { .... }
}
```

Could anybody kindly comment on whether this implementation REALLY fulfill the above-mentioned requirement? Any improvements needed?

Data are going to be persisted in SQL Server 2008 with NHibernate or EF using the code first approach!

Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: It would be nice with some more details on the usage scenario. Can you also explain why you choose to make `Registration` a value object?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Tommy! One usage scenario is that a user searches the archive for a vehicle, say with its license number and then gets the registration history of that vehicle displayed over a timeline, which might be implemented using Silverlight. **Registration** shouble be an entity as every registration has to be uniquely identified and immutable! Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Oops! **Registration** is mutable!

Answer (score 0):

Given such a simple requirement, this solution would seem fine. Hard to say much more without knowing the context. You mention the requirement was to view archived registrations so you should consider using that language in the code (`registrations` should be `archivedRegistrations` or `previousRegistrations` etc)